# Firebase Storage: Fail to download file even with public access

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am trying to test Firebase Storage. I manually uploaded images/egg.jpg.

I built a simple Android app to test the code from Firebase Guide in order to download the image. Just a button that enables the procedure.

The file **fails to download** and all I am getting is an exception from onFailure() that says "**User does not have permission to access this object**".

I saw similar questions and the solution was to allow read and write access to anyone through the rules, so I copied them as you can see below.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the activitys code

```
private StorageReference pathRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/egg.jpg");
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public void getImage(View v){
    File localFile;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("images","jpg");
        pathRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //Local temp file has been created
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //handle error
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage()+"\n"+e.getCause(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }catch (IOException exception){
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOEXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Just to be sure I also added these permissions to the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Why I cannot download the damn file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write:if true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that gives an error "Error saving rules - Line 5: Unexpected 'if'.
"

Comment: I changed,try again

Comment: Well that was it! What was the problem?

Comment: Before `allow read, write:` must be condition : `if true` or `request.auth != null;`(only for authenticated users)